# Searching a Parallel String Java

Tags: java

I am working on project here that stores some peoples names and phone numbers in a parallel array. I have that all figured out. I just need some ideas on how to have it search. For example a user should be able to enter a name or part of a name and it would output that name or names with the corresponding phone numbers. Here is what I have thus far:

```
public class PeoplesNumbers {
    private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> phoneNumber = new ArrayList<String>();

    //will allow to add names in main program
    public void plusName(String names, String phoneNumbers ) {
       name.add(names);
       phoneNumber.add(phoneNumbers);

    }

    /**
     * Good way to test program before making search method.
     * This will just test output of names in the main class. 
     */

    public void output() {
        for (int x = 0; x < name.size(); x++) {
            System.out.println(name.get(x) + ": ");
            System.out.println("\t" + phoneNumber.get(x));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}

public class Telemarketing {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //instance of PeopleNumbers Class
        PeoplesNumbers g1 = new PeoplesNumbers();
        g1.plusName("Harrision,Rose", "555-2234");
        g1.plusName("James, Jean", "555-9098");
        g1.plusName("Smith, William","555-1785" );
        g1.plusName("Smith, Brad", "555-9224");

        //This below was used to test program out before I made the search method
        g1.output();

    }

}
```

What suggestions do you have?

Comment: Don't use two lists: use a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: Would you want it to be part of the name as well? i.e. `arr` would give `Harrison,Rose`

Comment: Would that still be ok, if the requirement for this is to use a parallel array??

Answer (score 1):

This is the logic of what you need:

1. Create a search method that has a string as an argument.
2. Loop through the array of names. Use a for loop with an integer index.
3. Test each name to see if it contains the string parameter.
4. When you get a match, use the integer loop variable to access the array of names and print the name, use the same index to print the phone number.